# Loading website from Internet, and data from local files

Tags: android, webview, web, local, assets

I have a website that I'd like to load in WebView. However I have also files (such as images, *css, *js and so on) in assets folder that are needed to open that website. Is it possible to, while loading my website, use as much data from assets as possible and download all the rest from Internet in order to make my site load faster?

For example let's assume that my website needs two image files for proper looking: A and B. I have the A file in assets, but I haven't B at all. Is it possible to make WebView display website with A file from assets folder and B fetched from Internet?

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the complexity of your website, but assuming it's capable of running offline…

You could download the online content and store it locally in the same folder as the offline content. Then open it. So long as all the references in any downloaded script files are relative you shouldn't have a problem.

You might need to copy the local assets content from a read-only location to a read-write-location, but you could do that on first running the app.